# How to create comma seperated value in javascript on selection of values from multiple selection select box?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, multipleselection

I need the values selected from multipleselect select box as commaseperated values so that I can use these values in AJAX call to fetch the data from db table using these values.

Please help to me..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `multiSelect` is the select DOM object (obtained by `document.getElementById` for instance), then `resultString` will be the string you are looking for.

```
 var resultArray = [];
 for(var i=0; i < multiSelect.options.length; i++) {
     if (multiSelect.options[i].selected) {
         resultArray.push(multiSelect.options[i].value);
     }
  }
  var resultString = resultArray.join(",");
```

Comment: Thanks @nss, It worked for me without any editing, the way I wanted.. Thanks Again....